# Update Metaplex's token metadata - how to change the mutable parameter

Tags: spl-token, metaplex, metaboss

I'm using the `spl-token` command line.
What is the simplest way to change the token metadata (from the Metaplex Token Metadata program) and set mutable to false?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After instigations, you can use metaboss CLI to apply change on your token metadata:

metaboss set immutable --keypair 'path of config.json keypair' --account 'mint token account'

Details available at : https://metaboss.rs/set.html